# Am I using has_many, :through => right?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Question: How can I simplify this?

I'm using Rails 6.1.4

So I got the 3 tables contacts, lists and the bridge table between two tables called multicats.

I don't know if I'm doing it right or wrong... But it seems wrong and awkward. I've read the docs, tutorials in the past 24 hours and I'm still cloudy on this one...
SO, I got:

```
    create_table :multicats, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.belongs_to :list
      t.belongs_to :contact
    end

    create_table :contacts do |t|
       t.belongs_to :user
      t.string :email
      t.string :first_name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :lists do |t|
       t.belongs_to :user
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
```

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :multicats
  has_many :lists, :through => :multicats, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :multicats
  has_many :contacts, :through => :multicats, dependent: :destroy
end
```

So far so good I get it...

Now here's what I don't get.

When I create a contact I have to run a complicated set of lines... which seems so weird... And unorthodox.

Can't I just run 1 line and Rails takes care of everything? It usually does.

When I create a new record I have to do this:

```
... 
def create

@contact = Contact.new(first_name:  contact_params[:first_name], :email => contact_params[:email] , :user_id => current_user.id)
@contact.save!
 

mc=Multicat.new(:list_id => contact_params[:list], :contact_id => @contact.id , :user_id => current_user.id)
mc.save!

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        format.html { redirect_to contacts_url, notice: "Contact was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contact }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
...

 # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:first_name, :email, :list)
    end
```

It works, but...

How can I have it as a one-liner? I think this is wrong...

If I replace the first line with contact_params it errors out and says that attribute list doesn't exit. I don't know how to access it right and assign values.

Comment: A few reading sources that might help you: [`ActiveRecord#accepts_nested_attributes_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) and [`ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy#build`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-build)

Comment: @engineersmnky
So are you saying I should go with the ".build" rather than ".new" ?? How would you write it?

Comment: `current_user.contacts.build`, `current_user.multicats.build` and/or `@contact.multicats.build` would clean this up a bit but `accepts_nested_attributes_for` possibly even more so.

Comment: The "json style" colon hash syntax is generally preferred over hashrockets (`=>`). Whatever you do don't mix the two which will cause incontrollable spasms in any Rubyist https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#hash-literals.